# Problems with Euler $\phi$ function (2)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

1. If $a$, $b$ are coprime, then 
   $$a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}\equiv 1 \bmod (ab) \, .$$
2. If $\left(n=2\phi(n)\right)$, then $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: (1) is a generalization of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248219/two-problem-number-theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It is easy to use Euler's theorem to verify that $a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}=1$ (mod a), similarly $a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}=1$ (mod b). Since a,b are coprime we get:
$a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}=1$ (mod ab)

2)Let $n=i2^j$ (where i is odd). $\phi(n)=\phi(2^j)\phi(i)=2^{j-1}\phi(i)=n/2$, thus $n=2^j\phi(i)$. Therefore $\phi(i)=i$, hence $i=1$

Comment: why $\phi(i)$=i?andi=1?

Comment: if $\phi(i)=i$, it follows that all numbers in the set {1,2,...,i} are coprime to $i$, thus $i,i$ are coprime. Hence, $i=1$

Comment: Yes, which is $2^{a-1}$

Comment: @Amr: Oh sorry!

Comment: if  n isn't equal $i2^j$ then ...? can you solve this problem generality?

Comment: This is the contrapositive of what I proved.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 
For (2): Since $$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$
Saying that $n=2\varphi(n)$ is equivalent to $\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=\frac12$. Can you show that this implies that if $p|n$ then $p=2$?

Comment: I cann't show that n is power of 2,please help me.

Comment: Assume that there exists $p|n$, $p\neq 2$. Then $\frac{p-1}{p}$ appears in the product. Since $p+1$ is not a prime, $p$ does not appear in the numerator in any factor. Hence $p$ remains in the denumerator in the result as well.